# In IE9 dblclick on input box firing keydown and keyup event

Tags: internet-explorer, web, internet-explorer-9, mouseevent, onkeyup

I have a text field which is validated before submitting and certain handling of enter and escape buttons. code goes as follows

```
    i.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var k = IEBROWSER ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    console.log(" onkeyup "+event.keyCode+" "+e.keyCode);
    switch(k) {
        case 13:
            this.onchange();
            break;
        case 27: 
            textInvalid=false;
            this.cancelEdit(); 
            break;
        case 37: case 38: case 39: case 40:
            break;
        default:
            this.validate();
    }
}
```

If i double click on the text field onKeyUp and onKeyDown events are fired with the following logs

```
      onkeyup 67 67 
      onkeyup 17 17
```

Does anyone have any idea why it is fired? and why the key code 67 and 17 with single double click?

Here is the fiddle
           http://jsfiddle.net/Q2wU7/1/

Comment: Well, I can't confirm that. Neither on IE10 nor IE9. I'm running Win7... No keyup event on any mouse action.

Comment: There is a fiddle, can you check there? I am also running Win7

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that. :) No keyup here.

Comment: It is still behaving the same.